# What is the difference between rowCount() and hasChildren()?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I want to subclass `QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel`, and I found that it has two class methods that are very similar in function.

`rowCount()` and `hasChildren()`

I can use `rowCount()==0` to determine whether there are children. Why do I need a separate class method `hasChildren()`?

How are their roles different? Is `hasChildren()` necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rowCount() is not similar to hasChildren() since the first indicates the number of rows and the second if there are children. As you pointed out just when you compare rowCount with zero it might seem that they are equivalent. For example, in the case that the model does not have columns(columnCount() == 0) but has rows (rowCount() > 0), then will it have children? Well no, that's why in various models the QModelIndex is verified to be valid and that the number of columns or rows is greater than zero.

So if you want to verify that a QModelIndex has children it is better to use `hasChildren()` as well as it is more readable.

Comment: Do they influence each other or calculate independently?

Comment: @g2m.agent As I clearly pointed out in my answer: hasChildren depends on rowCount: *that's why in various models the QModelIndex is verified to be valid and that the number of columns or rows is greater than zero*.  But anyway it is better to have an explicit method hasChildren that allows to make a simple reading of the application. Why so much problem with that function? What's wrong with those features?

Comment: I think I understand. valid data has at least 1 row + 1 column, but for some reason, invalid data may have 1 row + zero columns. At this time, an overall judgment is required: IF (row>0 AND column>0): hasChildren=True;